# Oracle, filter by bits flags

Tags: oracle

I want to store a structure (Activity) with a Months field, the user can select 1 or more months for each activity, but I have to filter in a query by a specific month.

I have 4 approaches to store de data:

- I can create a table Activity_month that each row represents the activity with each month selected.
- Store in a Varchar2(12), and each month es a unique character.
- Store in a NUMBER(2), and each bit is a month, and the selected month is represented with 1, so the bit array 000100000011 represents that April, November, and December were selected.
- Create 12 Number(1) columns for each month.

Which one is better for store and search?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you will use it this data... Will you use it to filter data? How often? What filters will be most popular? So you need to answer a few questions:

1. Will you filter data just by one month? ie show me rows for April
2. Will you filter it as: give me those rows for April and June, but not January and December?
3. Will you aggregate rows by month?

> - Store in a NUMBER(2), and each bit is a month, and the selected month is represented with 1, so the bit array 000100000011 represents that April, November, and December were selected.
> - Create 12 Number(1) columns for each month.

You can use also virtual columns: for example, you can create 12 `Number(1)` columns and add virtual column
`generated as (jan*power(2,11)+feb*power(2,10)+...+dec*power(2,0))`.
But, since `Number(1)` takes 2 bytes, I'd prefer `varchar2(1 byte)` with `check(... in ('Y','N')` (or '0','1'):

```
SQL> select dump(cast(1 as number(1))) dmp_number_1 from dual;

DMP_NUMBER_1
--------------------
Typ=2 Len=2: 193,2

SQL> select dump(cast('Y' as varchar2(1))) dmp_varchar_1 from dual;

DMP_VARCHAR_1
--------------------
Typ=1 Len=1: 89
```

In this case you can create virtual column `generated as (jan||feb||...||dec)`.
Or even `winter as (jan||feb||dec)`

Then you will need to decide if you want to create indexes on them.